# how to make a tabbed page, when you have 6-7 pages to load?(css/jquery)

Tags: css, ajax, jquery

i want to make a css/jquery tabbed for an "Admin panel", so it will all be loaded without the need to refresh.
im going to do it dynamicly but its a small exercise site so i know ill have only 3-4 main "areas" to edit in the panel (the tabs in the top).
the thing is i have other links for each editing area.
is there a way to do it with jquery, without the need of putting all the code in 1 page,  in 3-4 divs and make them all invisble except the tabed being choosen(like ive seen in examples)?
in examples i saw all the content in one page, and if adding the top tabs and also the pages of each area(lets say delete, edit etc) its alot of code.

is there a comfortable way of doing it, while being able to make it dynamicly in the future?

edit to answers:

i already made tab from the this tutorial:
http://net.tutsplus.com/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-a-slick-tabbed-content-area/

the thing is, at first in the admin menu i have like 13-14 html pages(before it becomes php) with different operations.
how would you take 13 pieces of code(they have the layout and the admin+admin menu yet the content is changed) that should be in different files, and make them show up in the same tab?
would you have to split each code to only its div, and then load it someway?
from the tutorial above, they used all of the content in one page and used invisible......
how would you load 13 pieces?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [jQuery UI Tab Widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/):

- you can load the tab content statically or dynamically with AJAX
- it uses the jQuery CSS framework
- it's easy and full of sample code